# The state called from an event handler function does not contain the expected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, websocket

I have this component which I minimize as much as possible while debugging and can finally explain the behavior afterwards, it was hard to find the problem because I had some complex logic there, anyway:

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const DashboardNavbar = (props) => { 
  const socket = useContext(WebsocketContext);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);


  console.log("dashboard is rerendering...")

  const showCurrent = () => {
    console.log("showCurrent is running and current = ", current);
  };

  const incrementCurent = () => {
    setCurrent((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("newNotification", (payload) => {
      // ...
      showCurrent();
    });
    return () => {
      // Unregistering Events...
      socket.off("connect");
      socket.off("newNotification");
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          showCurrent();
        }}
      >
        show{" "}
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          incrementCurent();
        }}
      >
        increment
      </button>
    </>
  );
}  
export default DashboardNavbar;
```

As you can see I have a button to increment `current` state and when this happen the component rerenders so  I see the logs

```
dashboard is rerendering...
```

and then when I click the "show" button, i.e call `showCurrent` I am able to see the logs

```
showCurrent is running and current = N
```

where N is the expected value of `current`, so far so good, the problem is when "newNotification" is triggered so its event handler function runs, i.e `showCurrent`, **the same function**, however in this case, I always see the logs

```
showCurrent is running and current = 0
```

so no matter what it is the real-time value of `current`, it is always equal to `0` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood why this was happening.

In most cases we use event handlers inside JSX as `onClick`, `onChange`... so each time the component rerenders those functions are recreated therefore we don't face this kind of issue.

Here this one is different, I had `useEffect` with an empty dependency array so it will fire only once after the first render of the component so the event handler will always use the same referenced `showCurrent` version when that `useEffect` ran, and since at that time `current` was equal to `0` then it will always be equal to `0` there.

I figured out that I need to make the event handler references to the newest created `showCurrent` function each time `current` is updated, so then access the newest/expected value of `current`.

That being said, a strightforward solution is to include `current` in the depenncy array of the effect, this will make it fire each time `current` change value and doeq what we want it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
 socket.on("newNotification", (payload) => {
   //...
 });

 return () => {
    socket.off("connect");
    socket.off("newNotification");
 };
}, [current]); // include "current"
```

Here is a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-meadow-yv5386?file=/src/App.js), not with socket, since it is tricky to make one, but it is the exact same behavior.

---

Another solution is [Referencing a value with a ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#referencing-a-value-with-a-ref).
The idea is to to create a ref and store there the value of `current` each time it is updated

```js
const currentRef = useRef(null);
//...
useEffect(() => {
  currentRef.current = current // "current" property of the ref has nothing to do with "current" state this is only a coincidence
},[current])
```

Now even with an empty dependency array, the other `useEffect` can access the real-time value of `currentRef.current` and use it instead of `current` state.

This approach will not make the component unsubscribe/subscribe to "newConverstation" event each `current` is updated as it is happenning with in first one.